# WordPress - there is an error logged in the host's log file - is it important? How solve?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to track-down a problem and looking around everywhere in the system,
and noticed in the host's log file there is the following error:

```
[Wed Mar 20 11:21:38 2024] [error] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "new" in /home/www/-redacted-.com/wordpress/wp-settings.php on line 219
```

Looking at the 'settings.php' file - line 219 contains:

```
    ...
// Add magic quotes and set up $_REQUEST ( $_GET + $_POST )
    wp_magic_quotes();
    
    do_action( 'sanitize_comment_cookies' );
    
    /**
         * WordPress Query object
         * @global object $wp_the_query
         * @since 2.0.0
         */
        $wp_the_query =& new WP_Query();            /* <<<< line 219    */
        
        /**
         * Holds the reference to @see $wp_the_query
         * Use this global for WordPress queries
         * @global object $wp_query
         * @since 1.5.0
         */
        $wp_query =& $wp_the_query;
    ...
```

Is it important?
How correct/solve it?

Comment: Remove the ampersand from  `=&`, so it's just an equals sign. I'm not sure how old this code is, but I'd say you probably need to update Wordpress. It's a very important error because Parse errors will stop the script from loading.

Comment: Support for this syntax was removed a very long time ago. You need to update all the things.

Comment: That ampersand was removed on March 30, 2011, in WP 3.2. It is LOOOOOONG past time to update

Comment: `is it important?`...well a syntax error will prevent the code from running at all...so absolutely yes it's important.

Comment: Thanks.  Where would settings.php have originated?  It's an old site, but we have latest version of WP, and Theme (Shuttle).

Comment: wp-settings.php has always been there, and is still used. (Note that it's `wp-settings.php` causing the error, there is no straight `settings.php`) https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php has the current version

Comment: Thanks, will do - should this have been updated when WP was updated? Are there other files that might need updating?

Comment: I don't recognise version numbers in the .php files, and wp-settings.php has lines like: "@since  1.0.0".   Is there a process to refresh the whole wp site?  Might the host have an out-of-date wp pack?

Comment: Not sure why you think the host has to do with this. You are the one that puts the wordpress files on the server, so you have to deal with the outdated wordpress install yourself. Download wordpress, overwrite the files on the server via ftp with the downloaded files. And your problem is solved.

Comment: @Klaassiek "You are the one that puts the wordpress files on the server" - well not exactly :? - many years ago my predecessor just pressed a button on our host's CntlPanel saying: 'Install WP'.  Since then we've updated WP many times & site is now running 6.4.3 and all without ever needing ftp - they just press the Update WP button whenever the Admin Dashboard tells them there is a new version.

Comment: I read here: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/updating-wordpress/  which says "The upgrade process will affect all files and folders included in the main WordPress installation. This includes all the core files used to run WordPress."  So why was wp-settings.php not updated??? Now that you have helped me, should I now move this to a WP forum?

Comment: Possibly, since that's an installation/upgrade question, and not a specific programming question. We can tell you what's wrong with the code, but not why Wordpress didn't update the file

Comment: Wild guess, but your current installation might be that ancient that even wordpress itself cannot update the files. Overwriting the wordpress files with the current version will fix this.